# WinAPI ComboBox with fixed list of strings and custom data

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

have a question that has puzzled me several times and I always had to turn to owner-drawn solution - which is, however, what I don't wanna engage with this time. My problem is as the title says and here is a model situation in code:

```
HWND hComboBox=::CreateWindow(WC_COMBOBOX,NULL,WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | CBS_HASSTRINGS | CBS_DROPDOWN,10,10,100,100,hWnd,0,hInstance,NULL);
ComboBox_SetItemData(   hComboBox,
                        ComboBox_AddString(hComboBox,"My item 1"),
                        1234
                    );
ComboBox_SetItemData(   hComboBox,
                        ComboBox_AddString(hComboBox,"My item 2"),
                        5678
                    );
int i=ComboBox_FindString(hComboBox,0,1234); // <-- crash
ComboBox_SetCurSel(hComboBox, i );
```

Apparently, I want to identify each item by its associated custom data (1234 and 5678 in this case). I know I was able to do that in Delphi but haven't yet convinced pure WinAPI to do the same thing (obvious question is what's hidden behind the Delphi's out-of-the-box functionality).

Thanks for a reply.

Comment: The line marked with "crash" originally contained the ComboBox_FindItemData macro (however, this shouldn't matter given that both macros expand to the same message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CBS_HASSTRINGS` is meaningless in a non-owner draw combobox. In a non-owner draw combobox, every item has a string and an optional item of data, and `ComboBox_FindString` always looks for items using a string. Of course, `1234` isn't a valid string pointer. You're basically giving the control an invalid pointer and it's not surprising that it crashes :)

There's no built-in message that lets you search by item data in a non-owner draw combo, so you need to write your own, e.g.:

```
int iCount = ComboBox_GetCount(hComboBox), iFound = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++)
{
    if (ComboBox_GetItemData(hComboBox, i) == 1234)
    {
        iFound = i;
        break;
    }
}
```